# Java command line argument containing backslash

Tags: java, command-line-interface, backslash

I want to run something similar to the following:

```
java MyProgram C:\Path\To\My\File
```

When I do this and output the contents of the first argument, it outputs:

```
C:PathToMyFile
```

This works, however:

```
java MyProgram "C:\Path\To\My\File"
```

But I want to be able to do the first command instead of the second. How can I achieve this?

Comment: _But I want to be able to do the first command instead of the second_ Why?

Comment: In the future I want to be able to do java MyProgram PathA PathB PathC .... It's a bit tedious to add quotes to all these paths. I basically want to be able to copy and paste all these paths without needing to change anything.

Comment: You'll find the alternative is more tedious.

Comment: Note that Java should be smart enough to understand a path like `C:/Path/To/My/File` which doesn't require escaping in the command prompt.

Comment: What shell or terminal program are you running this from, and how are you producing the output? In the regular Windows command prompt, the backslash isn't special, and doesn't need escaping. Though using the quotes is good practice anyway, in case there are spaces or other special characters in the file name. Those backslashes may be disappearing at an unexpected point, like `printf` processing inside your program. Can you include your code?

Comment: I was using the Git bash. I didn't realize the Windows command line would have been different from it.

Answer (score 1):

The `\` charecter is used to "escape" special characters. This means it tells the program to ignore them, or not do anything special to them. To make this work just use `\\` instead of `\`. This escapes the `\`. So use

```
C:\\Path\\To\\My\\File
```